# bash read into array

Tags: arrays, bash, while-loop, pipe, subshell

can you please tell me why this is not working?
only the add 'e f' after the read loop is done, but not the multiple adds 'q w' inside the read loop.
regards stefan

````
vuser1@vpc1:~$ echo ${#a[@]}
1
vuser1@vpc1:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
vuser1@vpc1:~$ set -x
vuser1@vpc1:~$ a=();ls -l|while read x; do a+=("q w");done;a+=("e f")
+ a=()
+ ls --color=auto -l
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("q w")
+ read x
+ a+=("e f")
vuser1@vpc1:~$ echo ${#a[@]}
+ echo 1
1
vuser1@vpc1:~$ echo ${a[@]}
+ echo e f
e f
vuser1@vpc1:~$```
````

Comment: Btw.: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: When executing a pipeline, you execute it in a subshell. This means that variable assignments are only known to that subshell. After the pipeline, the assignments are unknown to the original shell. Use redirection instead: `while IFS= read -r line; do a+=( "$line" ); done < <(command)`

Comment: `a=();while read x; do a+=( "q w" );done < <(ls -l);a+=( "e f" ); echo "${a[@]}"`

Comment: hi, thank you all for the help. i would never have come to the reason with subshell. here i found now another solution in google with herestring ```a=();while read x; do a+=("$x");done <<< "$(ls)";echo ${#a[@]}``` or just ```a=(`ls`)```

Comment: here i found another working solution for storing whitespaced command outputs into array:```pi@raspi:~ $ a=();while read x; do a+=("$x");done <<< "$(grep -inrE '/usr/lib/cgi-bin' /etc/apache2/)";echo ${#a[@]};echo ${a[1]}``` the good thing in this is, that no need to edit and restore this IFS thing.